# Javascript dialog doesn't Load data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using html divs as dialog popups & I declare them like this:

> < div id="div_name"  style="display: none;"> < /div>

on JS I declare this

```
$("#div_name").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 'auto',
width: 'auto',
});
```

and I assign it some information (< li>1< /li>< li>2< /li>...) loaded from Database

I use this for open it and close it many times in a row

```
$("#div_name").dialog('open');
$("#div_name").dialog('close');
```

the first time I open it, the information is fine (this info is loaded from DB everytime I open the dialog) but by the 3rd or 4th time, the information doesn't show in the dialog, what could be happening with the dialog that doesn't display the information, if Somebody could help me it would be great, thanks a lot for your time & answers.

Comment: we need more code about how you load the data from database using the ajax call.

Comment: Do you persist the information on the client? You may have to do some kind of AJAX request to your server to re-load the data.

Comment: Show us some more Code